# React native fetch blob causing error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-fetch-blob

**Problem**
I added react native fetch blob to my react native (expoKit) project. I ran `rnpm link` in the console. When I opened android studio and tried to build the project, I got this error:

```
Error:(54, 55) error: incompatible types: expolib_v1.okhttp3.OkHttpClient cannot be converted to okhttp3.OkHttpClient
```

and also:

```
Error:(24, 15) error: cannot find symbol class JavaNetCookieJar
```

I have no idea what it causing these errors, and I would love some help fixing them.

Answer (score 1):

Expo doesn't support "React native fetch blob" yet

Comment: It's expokit not expo